# Express JS session cleanup

Tags: node.js, express, session, session-storage

I don't know what I missed, when [expressjs session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) removes the old expired session from storage? Does it do that?

Comment: Can you clarify please ?

Comment: @BENARDPatrick I am not sure If I understand it correctly or not, but if I attach storage to 'express session`, it stores every session there in the attached storage, when and how those records in the storage got cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the underlying session store could have a TTL/expiry associated to the session record. The TTL would be used by the store to clean up the expired records so there no other server-side process or any trigger from `session` package to delete expired records.